# Excel sort whole table followed by sort of a part of the table

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have the following Excel table:

| Customer Name | Total Sales | Percentage of Group Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 Corp | 10000 | 15% |
| ABC2 Corp | 11000 | 20% |
| ABC3 Corp | 8000 | 15% |
| ABC4 Corp | 6000 | 20% |
| ABC5 Corp | 20000 | 25% |
| ABC6 Corp | 9000 | 25% |
| ABC7 Corp | 30000 | 25% |

I want to first sort the whole table by Percentage of Group Sales (smallest to largest) then Customer Name (A to Z), which would give me this following table:

| Customer Name | Total Sales | Percentage of Group Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 Corp | 10000 | 15% |
| ABC3 Corp | 8000 | 15% |
| ABC2 Corp | 11000 | 20% |
| ABC4 Corp | 6000 | 20% |
| ABC5 Corp | 20000 | 25% |
| ABC6 Corp | 9000 | 25% |
| ABC7 Corp | 30000 | 25% |

I would like to then sort the part of the table where Percentage of Group Sales = 25% by Total Sales. The result would be like this table:

| Customer Name | Total Sales | Percentage of Group Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC1 Corp | 10000 | 15% |
| ABC3 Corp | 8000 | 15% |
| ABC2 Corp | 11000 | 20% |
| ABC4 Corp | 6000 | 20% |
| ABC6 Corp | 9000 | 25% |
| ABC5 Corp | 20000 | 25% |
| ABC7 Corp | 30000 | 25% |

Is there a way I can automate this using any of the tools inside Excel (using the sort tool in the Data tab) or using VBA?

Comment: Why not sort by percentage _and_ group sales?

Comment: Add a helper column that has an IF statement along the lines of "=IF([Percentage of Group Sales] = .25, [Total Sales], [Customer Name]) and then use that as your second sort key.

Comment: Btw you can also use `SORT()` function --> `=SORT(A2:C8,{3,1})` if you want to have the header then, `=VSTACK(A1:C1,SORT(A2:C8,{3,1}))`

Comment: @cybernetic_nomad I do that using the Sort utility under the Data tab.